# Making one handler debounced for all input elements in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debouncing

I have a parent component with a state holding the data and a handler to update it upon any input element change.

Now I want to improve performance as this handler is doing quite a lot of validations, so I would like to wait until the last keystroke before starting the validations but I still want the input to react to users typing.

The issue is when I debounce my handler, it works but in the time of the debounce delay if I switch to a different input element fast and start typing it will delete the old event so I'm stuck with the result inside the element but with validation only on the second element.

I tried to create a new function that will call that handler to make each a diffrerent instance so they wont block each other but it didnt work.

Tried to copy the function and then run it, no luck.

I also tried setting timeout by myself, which did work but then I didnt manage to find a way to stop it on new event :(

Im stuck with debouncing the handler on the constructor level:

```
this.onAdvancedChange = debounce(this.onAdvancedChange, 500);
```

which is exactly what I described before.

There is two handlers one which is not debounced to react to input typing:

```
onSimpleChange({ target }) {
  const newData = ...; // Im copying target data to a new object here to pass instead.
  setState(..., () => this.onAdvancedChange({ target: newData }));
}
```

```
onAdvancedChange({ target }) {
  validate(target);  
  if needed -> setState(...);
}
```

It does work, but again when I switch fast to a different input and start typing while the prev debounce didnt hit yet, it wont hit at all and only the second will validate.

How Do I make my advanced handler private for each input call, or maybe the other option I tried to use timeout but then how to stop it on every new event for each input individualy?

Thank you a LOT in advance.

Comment: Could you simply also validate on ‘blur’? (I.e: event fired when element looses focus)

Comment: I could, thanks. but the client wanted us to dog feed the clients so they can finish it quite fast as there is a lot of questions. onBlur is defenetly what I will do if I wont find better solution for this case.